# The DASHes here are quite misleading for me. Does the sentence mean that Liege and Utrecht are under the Archbishopric of Cambrai?

Tags: punctuation

His dominions were split up by ecclesiastical lands, above all by the Archbishopric of Cambrai on the borders of France and Germany - of Liege, spread out in a wide semicircle between Hainault and Luxembourg and reaching as far to the north as Maaseyk - of Utrecht whose eastern half was separated from the western by the large county of Gelderland, still a direct fief of the Empire.

Comment: This is an incredibly confusing sentence, even for native English speakers. But I would guess what it means is that his dominions were split up by three archbishoprics: the Archbishoprics of Cambrai, of Liege, and of Utrecht.

Comment: In answer to your question "No, it does not". There are three archbishoprics.The example is very poorly written and needs editorial intervention to be reader-friendly. There is also a critical error.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's a sentence I encountered in The Emperor Charles V, a book translated into English from other language. I found it confusing and so I posted here. I have checked and found that Cambrai used to be an archbishopric but Liege and Utrecht were prince-bishoprics. It seems that the translator had made mistakes.